# How do i get url image when i post my url on facebook?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

When I post this url (http://www.webnersolutions.com/salesforce) on facebook it shows saleforce image but when i post this url (http://ilikeuapp.webnersolutions.com/fbshare?id=245) it shows site logo but I want app logo according to this url. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your pages contain no Open Graph tags. Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-properties#standard

Comment: but i have so many url's like:- http://ilikeuapp.webnersolutions.com/app-details?id=245 , http://ilikeuapp.webnersolutions.com/app-details?id=254,
http://ilikeuapp.webnersolutions.com/app-details?id=241,                      so i need these images dynamically using og: image( ) it will give only one image.

Comment: Well, you can create the tags automatically and fill the right values if you use PHP, obviously... How should it work otherwise? Facebook can't guess what you would like to be displayed while sharing. That's what OpenGraph is for.